# REST API GET for multiple items and individual items

Tags: api, rest

As I understand it, when creating a REST API to get multiple items the path would be

`GET v1/items`

For a single item the path would be

`GET v1/items/{itemId}`

Is it considered good practice to combine them so one end point could deal with whether an itemId was provided or not and default to providing multiple records if not.

If it is, what would be the correct path for the. Does the second one cover both or is there a tweak to allow for the itemId being optional?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it considered good practice to combine them so one end point could deal with whether an itemId was provided or not and default to providing multiple records if not.

As far as [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is concerned, it's fine.  REST doesn't constrain your resource model, so if your resource were an HTML document describing the collection of items, you could use one layout when there is a single item and a different layout when there are multiple items, and that would be fine.

BUT... in the case where *programs*, rather than *people* are trying to consume the information -- the consumers of your API are not likely to be happy that you are pushing more complexity onto them, rather than choosing a resource model that hides the complexity behind the API facade.

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice is definitive to have 2 endpoints.

But when you only have one, i would name it like

```
GET v1/items/{itemId?}
```

The question mark symbolizes that an ID can be given, but it is not a must